# Android internal storage mechanism

Tags: android, kotlin, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I am trying to understand how Android internal storage works.
For that I read a few tutorials and a number of posts on StackOverFlow.

Nevertheless things are not all that clear when testing real code.

Here is one problem, the following code is meant to create a directory and a file:

```
val dirName = "myNewDir"
createDir(dirName)

val fileName = "myNewFile"
writeToFile("Some random text for testing purpose ...",fileName)

val directory = filesDir

val files: Array<File> = directory.listFiles()
println("Files count = "+files.size)

for (f in files) {
    println("Name: "+f.name)
}
```

This is the code for the two functions createDir() and writeToFile() :

```
fun createDir(dirName:String): File? {
    return applicationContext.getDir(dirName, MODE_PRIVATE)
} /* End of createDir */


fun writeToFile(dataBufr:String, fileName:String) {
    applicationContext.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
            output -> output.write(dataBufr.toByteArray())
    }
} /* End of writeToFile */
```

And this is what appears in the console when executing the code above:

```
I/System.out: Files count = 1
I/System.out: Name: myNewFile
```

My question is:
Why is the directory (myNewDir) not created or at list does not appear in the console?

Comment: If you use openFileOutput() the file will be saved in getFilesDir(). You only supply a file name. It makes no sense to create directories somewhere else. Also not in getFilesDir().

Comment: `createDir(dirName)` That is wrong coding. Allways check the result of a function. `if(!createDir(dirName)) { toast(...) return;}`

Comment: OK, but that does not answer my question. Why is the directory not created? "Does creating a directory here makes sense or not?" is a different issue. Beside I also tried using code like : writeToFile("some text ....",File(dirName, "myNewFile2").name). But it did not create any directory.

Comment: I tried this code: if(createDir(dirName) == null) {
            println("createDir NOT WORKING")
            return;
        }
But it seems like the createDir is working. So I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: You check for null. But what does createDir() return? Can it return null?

Comment: `But it did not create any directory` Of course not. It creates a file. Confusing talk. You should have told instead that openFileOutput does not create a file. You only name your own function. But how are you checking if the file is created? Or eventually a directory? You should better tell what you do.

Comment: As one can see with the code in my post,
createDir() returns an objet of type File? Therefore it can be null.
According to the tutorials I saw, I expect createDir() to create a directory.
But no directory is created (this was the point of my question).
I know that writeToFile() has created a file (myNewFile) because I can see it listed in the console. There is no confusion here.

Comment: You are pretty well confusing me with your code. You are testing two statements. But for every statement you make your own function. Terrible if you ask for help. Just do away with these two functions of your own. Post two code examples: one for creating a directory. One for creating a file. Adapt your post please as i cannot follow you as it is a mess. Sorry.

Comment: @blackapps. OK, accepting that my post may be confusing. I made a new one dealing solely with the issue of creating (and listing) directories and without any function of mine. This is the URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382597/creating-directories-within-android-internal-storage. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Latest android version, all default dirs will be created in the first open by LoadAPK.java, `getDir` will get the exists dir.

```java
public File getDir(String name, int mode) {
    checkMode(mode);
    name = "app_" + name;
    File file = makeFilename(getDataDir(), name);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
        setFilePermissionsFromMode(file.getPath(), mode,
                FileUtils.S_IRWXU|FileUtils.S_IRWXG|FileUtils.S_IXOTH);
    }
    return file;
}
```

In the `getDataDir()`

```java
@Override
public File getDataDir() {
    if (mPackageInfo != null) {
        File res = null;
        if (isCredentialProtectedStorage()) {
            res = mPackageInfo.getCredentialProtectedDataDirFile();
        } else if (isDeviceProtectedStorage()) {
            res = mPackageInfo.getDeviceProtectedDataDirFile();
        } else {
            res = mPackageInfo.getDataDirFile();
        }

        if (res != null) {
            if (!res.exists() && android.os.Process.myUid() == android.os.Process.SYSTEM_UID) {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "Data directory doesn't exist for package " + getPackageName(),
                        new Throwable());
            }
            return res;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "No data directory found for package " + getPackageName());
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "No package details found for package " + getPackageName());
    }
}
```

In the `frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/LoadedApk.java` all file will be init by ApplicationInfo.

```java
private void setApplicationInfo(ApplicationInfo aInfo) {
    final int myUid = Process.myUid();
    aInfo = adjustNativeLibraryPaths(aInfo);
    mApplicationInfo = aInfo;
    mAppDir = aInfo.sourceDir;
    mResDir = aInfo.uid == myUid ? aInfo.sourceDir : aInfo.publicSourceDir;
    mLegacyOverlayDirs = aInfo.resourceDirs;
    mOverlayPaths = aInfo.overlayPaths;
    mDataDir = aInfo.dataDir;
    mLibDir = aInfo.nativeLibraryDir;
    mDataDirFile = FileUtils.newFileOrNull(aInfo.dataDir);
    mDeviceProtectedDataDirFile = FileUtils.newFileOrNull(aInfo.deviceProtectedDataDir);
    mCredentialProtectedDataDirFile = FileUtils.newFileOrNull(aInfo.credentialProtectedDataDir);

    mSplitNames = aInfo.splitNames;
    mSplitAppDirs = aInfo.splitSourceDirs;
    mSplitResDirs = aInfo.uid == myUid ? aInfo.splitSourceDirs : aInfo.splitPublicSourceDirs;
    mSplitClassLoaderNames = aInfo.splitClassLoaderNames;

    if (aInfo.requestsIsolatedSplitLoading() && !ArrayUtils.isEmpty(mSplitNames)) {
        mSplitLoader = new SplitDependencyLoaderImpl(aInfo.splitDependencies);
    }
}
```

`frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/FileUtils.java`

```
public static @Nullable File newFileOrNull(@Nullable String path) {
    return (path != null) ? new File(path) : null;
}

public static @Nullable File createDir(File baseDir, String name) {
    final File dir = new File(baseDir, name);

    return createDir(dir) ? dir : null;
}

public static boolean createDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.mkdir()) {
        return true;
    }

    if (dir.exists()) {
        return dir.isDirectory();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: At this point I am just trying to create a few empty directories and then simply list them to make sure they have been created and they still exist. But even this simple thing is not working.

Comment: er, you mean directory not print on console? directory.listFiles() just list all children exclude itself.you can change `println("Name: "+f.name)` -> `println("Name: "+f.absolutePath)`,

Comment: Thanks but this does not solve the problem, the same information is only output in another format.

Comment: I made a more restrictive post to narrow the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382597/creating-directories-within-android-internal-storage.