# Creating directories within Android internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I have some problems with creating and then listing directories within Android internal storage.

This is the kotlin code I execute in my app:

```
    var dirStatus = applicationContext.getDir("One", MODE_PRIVATE)
    println("dirStatus = "+dirStatus)
    dirStatus = applicationContext.getDir("Two", MODE_PRIVATE)
    println("dirStatus = "+dirStatus)
    dirStatus = applicationContext.getDir("Three", MODE_PRIVATE)
    println("dirStatus = "+dirStatus)
```

This is what I see in the console once the code above is executed:

```
    I/System.out: dirStatus = /data/user/0/me.soft.myapp/app_One
    I/System.out: dirStatus = /data/user/0/me.soft.myapp/app_Two
    I/System.out: dirStatus = /data/user/0/me.soft.myapp/app_Three
    D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl: asyncReportData me.soft.myapp,2,1,1,0 interval=249
    I/software.crayo: Starting profile saver IsSaveProfileNow end.
```

Now here is my question, assuming that three empty directories (One,Two,Three) have just been created.
What is the code that will allow me to list those three directories?

If I am asking this is because the code below which I expected to do the job did not work:

```
    val directory:File
    directory = getFilesDir()
    val files: Array<File> = directory.listFiles()
    println("Files count: "+files.size)
    for (f in files) {
        println("Name:"+f.name)
    }
```

Comment: new File(getDir("Michel")).listFiles().

Comment: getFilesDir().listFiles().

Comment: println("files dir: " + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()). You should have compared the paths to begin with. They are different.

Comment: Maybe getDir("Michel").listFiles() compiles already if also here a File object is returned.

Comment: getDir("Michel").getAbsolutePath().

Comment: To list those three directories: getDir("Michel").getParentFile().listFiles().

Comment: Try getAbsilutePath() for getDir(null) and getDir("").

Comment: @blackapps. Thanks but I don't understand what you are trying to say in all the comments above. Please write an answer with the kotlin code you think will work.

Comment: Stackoverflow and i are not code providing services. You got enough hints now to come to a solution. Did you try all hints? It seems not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public abstract File getFilesDir()` means `/data/user/0/xxx/files` not `/data/user/0/xxx/`

```kotlin
val a = applicationContext.getDir("aaaa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
applicationContext.getDir("bbbb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
applicationContext.getDir("cccc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

// print nothing
applicationContext.filesDir.listFiles()?.forEach { file ->
    Log.d("MainActivity", "file path: ${file.absolutePath}")
}

// print a parent directory
a.parentFile?.listFiles()?.forEach { file ->
    Log.d("MainActivity", "file path: ${file.absolutePath}")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, now I see what is going on. The directories made by me have been prepended with "app_". As a best practice should I create my custom directories as I did or do that under files?

Comment: as my taste, I'd like `applicationContext.getDir("One", MODE_PRIVATE)` any time.

Comment: as my taste, I'd like `applicationContext.getDir("One", MODE_PRIVATE)` any time and use `filesdir`,`cachedir` or others api as they use for.[https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage), in fact new file do the same thing. all files will be deleted when the app is uninstalling.

Comment: I have added an image but it with some Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but It may be helpful to you.

```
val myFile = File(path)
val files: Array<File> = myFile.listFiles()
for (f in files) {
    if (f.isDirectory) {
        // Do your stuff  
        Log.e("TAG", "onCreate : "+ f.name ) 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is path? In your first line of code.

Comment: Internal storage path where directory is created/stored, Path is like Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + FOLDER_LOCATION.

Comment: So you mean "/data/user/0/me.soft.myapp/" in my case ?

Comment: Yes try that one. where your directory is listed in main folder.

Comment: I just tried without success. I used this code:  val myFile = File("/data/user/0/me.soft.myapp/"). But you can see in my code how I create the 3 directories. So you should see how to list them, am I wrong? Do you need more information?

Comment: Firstly Make log of size and check, is it get correct or not as per your storage directory?

Comment: Log.e("TAG", "onCreate : "+ f.name )  Try this. Check Code i will update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247323/discussion-between-bhavin-solanki-and-michel).